# Emacs evil mode - How can I mimic the 'ex-showmarks' Vim plugin?

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

The Vim ['ex-showmarks'](https://github.com/exvim/ex-showmarks) plugin visually displays Vim marks in a file gutter, something like this:

[image: After marking with 'ma' and 'mb']

I miss this functionality and am trying to find a way to replicate it in Emacs evil mode, and would like to make sure there's not some quick solution I'm missing before I try to learn how to write Emacs extensions.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a package that does exactly what you want, but there's a package called `bm` (bookmark) that's fairly close.  It does highlighting, but you need to manually insert the bookmarks.  You could adapt it to highlight the marks in `mark-ring`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no package to highlight evil markers. However, it should not be too difficult to implement. The list of markers is stored in the variable `evil-markers-alist` (see the function `evil-show-marks` for an example how to access this data). Hence, one only needs to traverse this list and add appropriate overlays to the buffer.

It might be a good idea to add an advice to the function `evil-set-marker`, which is called whenever Evil changes a mark, so that the highlighting can be updated.

I would probably define a minor mode `evil-show-marks-mode` or so to enable/disable this feature.

Because it is a nice feature and quite easy but not trivial to implement, it would be nice if someone volunteers to write a corresponding extension package ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a package that does this, [evil-visual-mark-mode](https://github.com/roman/evil-visual-mark-mode).

Which shows mars inline in normal-mode.

Once installed, simply add `(evil-visual-mark-mode)` to your config to enable globally.